# AS ____ not working in "Union select statement"

Tags: sql, union

I have this:

```
SELECT
COUNT(resurs_id) AS 'antalLikes'
FROM kopplaResursLikesUsers
WHERE resurs_id = 19
UNION
SELECT user_id AS 'gillarJagEller'
FROM kopplaResursLikesUsers
WHERE user_id = 5
```

And I thought the output would be:

```
antalLikes = 2
gillarJagEller = 5
```

but the result I get is:

```
antalLikes[0] = 2
antalLikes[1] = 5
```

Any ideas why it completely ignores my 2nd "AS" statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`UNION` does make an `UNION` for `COLUMS`, not for `rows`
So, it's taking the first select, get the `column 'antalLikes'`
and then make the `union` by the ordinal order.
So, it put the values from your `'gillarJagEller' column` in the first one

to get your desired result, I suggest this:

```
select
(
SELECT
COUNT(resurs_id) 
FROM kopplaResursLikesUsers
WHERE resurs_id = 19) AS 'antalLikes',
(
 SELECT user_id 
 FROM kopplaResursLikesUsers
 WHERE user_id = 5) AS 'gillarJagEller'
```

Answer (score 1):

UNION takes as column names only the names specified in the first select statement, in this case, "antalLikes".

To get this:

antalLikes = 2 gillarJagEller = 5

You need something like this:

```
SELECT
COUNT(resurs_id) AS 'antalLikes', 
(SELECT top 1 user_id
FROM kopplaResursLikesUsers
WHERE user_id = 5) AS 'gillarJagEller'
FROM kopplaResursLikesUsers
WHERE resurs_id = 19
```

Answer (score 1):

Column names and column data types in a `UNION` are provided by the first `select` statement in the `UNION`. Any column names in subsequent `select statements are ignored.

Subsequent `select` statements in the `UNION` are required to have the same number of columns as the first `select` statement. Further, each column in each subsequent `select` statement must have a datatype that is identical to the column with the same ordinal number in the first `select` statement or is implicitly convertible to that data type.

WRT to nullity, I believe `UNION` sets the nullity of each column in the final result set by examining the nullity of that same column in each component `select` statement. Only if that column is non-nullable across each component `select` statement is the column in the final result set non-nullable.